# How to share properties between different classes in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

what do i have to do if i want to acess or change properties of one class in different controllers?icreated a class info,with two properties,teams and players,,For example,i wanna set number of teams in one controller,number of players in another an then use them in the third one?how to manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reference that class. Go to the .h file and type above @`interface` of MyClassTwo...

```
@class MyClassOne
```

And you create and object for MyClassOne inside the `@interface` of MyClassTwo and set that as a `property` and `synthesize` it

Now in the @`implementation` of MyClassTwo, you should be able to the access the properties of MyClassOne with the object of MyClassOne.

Comment: Oh,no.It almost works,i mean,it builds,but it just doesn't save those values.even in one method,i justhave two lines,one by one,(iv created an "info" object and prop in the second class,synthesized that,bu,what kind of props that has to be?retain,yes?)so in one line i write info.team = 128;And the NSLog(@"%d",info.team); and it logs zero.damn

Answer (score 0):

You would normally create model, an NSObject to hold the 'state' of your data and this can then be used by all of your controllers to render. The model will have properties for teams, players etc.

Comment: Yep!that's really what ive tryed to do-i created that NSobject with properties,but i just can't set those props-for example,in one view controller,i've got somebuttonpressed method,and there i write Info.team = smth; and the compilers says that"property team not found on object of type Info"?i understand,that i don't understand some fundamentall stuff,so what's wrong here?

Comment: Ahhh ok, so you have a variable - NSString *team; then at the bottom add a @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *team; and then in the implementation @synthesize team;

Comment: No,you tell me about using the properties of a class in the same clas,that's easy,but i just want to get them from the other classes.Is that the right way,in general,to store some data,or people don't do like that?)I mean,i juat began,so i understood the MVC this way: i create a NSobject class,make some props there.i want to store some data there.I have three viewcontrollers,two of them want to put some data there,the third one's gonna use.I can alloc-init an object of model class in 1 vc,but i won't be able to use those data in another by this method.how to do that then?)

Comment: I think you misunderstand, adding @property means that it is accessible from OUTSIDE the class, if you don't have those declarations then you get the error you are receiving....

Comment: All the properties are declared,@class Info; is declred in teamviewcontroller,ivar created there,property Info* info declated,synthesyzed,and then,in .m i say info.team = 128;Nslog,and its zero.